# why modal with ajax does not close correctly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I need help, I have tried in many ways (several of them are in the forum and nothing)

In the index I have a link_to where I open the modal and below is the div with the id of the modal.

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Nuevo equipo', new_team_path, {class:"btn btn-success",:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window-new' } %>
...
<div id="modal-window-new" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
<% @tipo = 'Nuevo Equipo'
  js = escape_javascript(
  render(partial: 'teams/form', locals: {  team: @team  })
) %>
$("#modal-window-new").html("<%= js %>");
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" ><%= @tipo %></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </div>
       <%= form_for team, remote: true do |form| %>
       <div class="modal-body">

        <%= form.label  "Obligatorio (*)", class: "col-form-label" %>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <% if team.errors.any? %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= pluralize(team.errors.count, "error/es") %> antes de agregar un equipo:</strong><br>
                <% team.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <%= message %><br>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :nombre_equipo, "Nombre Equipo*", class: "col-form-label" %>
          <%= form.text_field :nombre_equipo, class: "form-control",  id: :team_nombre_equipo %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :ciudad_equipo, "Ciudad Equipo*", class: "col-form-label" %>
          <%= form.text_field :ciudad_equipo, class: "form-control", id: :team_ciudad_equipo %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :restriccion_horario, "Restricción Horario", class: "col-form-label" %>
          <%= form.text_field :restriccion_horario, class: "form-control", id: :team_restriccion_horario %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :camiseta, class: "col-form-label" %>
          <%= form.text_field :camiseta, class: "form-control", id: :team_camiseta %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :pantaloneta, class: "col-form-label" %>
          <%= form.text_field :pantaloneta, class: "form-control", id: :team_pantaloneta %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :medias, class: "col-form-label" %>
          <%= form.text_field :medias, class: "form-control", id: :team_medias %>
        </div>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $("select#team_select").select2();
          }); </script>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= form.label :delegate_id, "Delegado:*" %>
         <%#= form.select(:delegate_id, Delegate.all, :id, :nombre, {include_blank: "None"}, {id: "team_select"}) %>
         <%= collection_select(:team, :delegate_id, Delegate.all, :id, :nombre_del_completo, {:multiple => false, :include_blank => true}, {class: "form-control", id: "team_select"})%><br><br>
        </div>

       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <%= form.submit "Guardar", class: "btn btn-success"%>
       </div>
       <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And he tried with

```
  $('#modal-window-new').modal('hide');
```

in no way the modal is closed, by the way we already have the app on a server.

thank you very much!

**----------------------------------------------**

**Upgrade**

update.js.erb

```
<% if not @team.errors.any? %>
  $('#modal-window-new').modal('hide');
  console.info($('#modal-window-new'));
<% else %>
  <% @tipo = 'Editar Equipo'
    js = escape_javascript(
    render(partial: 'teams/form', locals: {  team: @team  })
  ) %>
  $("#modal-window-edit").html("<%= js %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: when are you trying to close the modal, you need to do it inside an event like clicking of some element or link `$('.close-button').click(function(){ $('#modal-window-new').modal('hide'); })`

Comment: Can you show us where he used ' $('#modal-window-new').modal('hide');' ? in create.js or update.js ? I am also using this and it's working. Can you add a console.info($('#modal-window-new')); after the statement and then look in your Firebug oder Inspector Console what the output is?

Comment: I have already tried placing the event of clicking on a button and nothing happens, I do not know if it is because of the location where I put the event or for something else

Comment: I checked my files: try <div id="modal-window-new" class="modal hide fade in" .

Comment: OK. Do I understand correctly? You aren't a Rails developer and trying to fix things in production ? If that's correct than I cannot recommend this! Please don't. Regarding your problem I will add a longer answer.

Comment: result of console.info after of hide:
r.fn.init [div#modal-window-new.modal.hide.fade.in]
0
:
div#modal-window-new.modal.hide.fade.in.show
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Object(0)

Answer (score 0):

After the form is getting submitted the update.js is getting rendered. You have to put the js statement in there:

```
$('#modal-window-new').modal('hide');
```

If a new model is getting created you have to add it to the create.js file.

in your case maybe located under /app/views/teams/...

A better update.js or create.js is to handle the model is:

```
<% if not @team.errors.any? %>
  $('#modal-window-new').modal('hide');
  // do other updates here
<% else %>
  $('#modal-window').show();
  // todo: render partial again into the modal
<% end %>
// todo: show some errors
```

Comment: I am a beginner in rails, but I do not try to solve the error in production, I know it is bad practice.
With respect to create.js it's the same as new.js, I'll try what you suggest.
But new.js I leave it like this?

Comment: If you can see the modal than the new.js works correct.

Comment: What you mean with "create is same? Same as new.js ?

Comment: yes i can see the modal.

 I want to say that both new.js and create.js are different files but they have the same content, change the create.js when I saw your answer